# How to condense and remap data of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce, remap

I have this array of data and need a remapped version of it to iterate through the dates.

```
var objArr = [
     {"Country": "US", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2"},
     {"Country": "US", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2"},
     {"Country": "CN",  "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"},
     {"Country": "CN", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"}
   ]
```

- The countries should sum their values and should not appear twice in the inner array.
- At the end I wanna have an array like this:

```
     var remapped = [
       {"2017-07-12": [
                    {"Country: "US", "value": 3}, 
                    {"Country: "CN", "value": 10}],
       {"2017-07-13": [
                    {"Country: "US", "value": 4},
                    {"Country: "US", "value": 14}]
     ]
```

In my current case, I get this, but countries should get reduced and the value summed:

```
var remapped = [
   {"2017-07-12": [
                {"Country: "US", "value": 1}, 
                {"Country: "US", "value": 2}, 
                {"Country: "CN", "value": 5}],
                {"Country: "CN", "value": 5}
                  ],
   {"2017-07-13": [
                {"Country: "US", "value": 2},
                {"Country: "US", "value": 2},
                {"Country: "US", "value": 7}
                {"Country: "US", "value": 7}
                 ]
 ]
```

This is what I've so far. But for me, it seems overcomplicated, and I am sure that there is a far more efficient way to solve that: 
At this state I have the countries remapped into the dates, but not sure how to "reduce" them. Do I really have to multiple iterates over the arrays?

```
const res = [];
dateArray.forEach(date => (objArr[date] = [])); // I create an array with dates which could contain another array

objArr.forEach(item => {
  dates.forEach(date => {
    res[date].push({
      Country: item['Country'],
      value: item[date],
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using `reduce` method and first store values for each date in one object so you can group them by Country and then convert those objects to arrays.

```js
var data = [
 {"Country": "US", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2"},
 {"Country": "US", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2"},
 {"Country": "CN",  "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"},
 {"Country": "CN", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"}
]

const result = data.reduce((r, {Country, ...rest}, i) => {
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if(!r[k]) r[k] = {}
    if(!r[k][Country]) r[k][Country] = {Country, value: +v}
    else r[k][Country].value += +v
  })
  
  return r;
}, {})

for(let i in result) {
  result[i] = Object.values(result[i])
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This output seems a much more logical format than the one requested, but note that it is different.  It's asking for an array of one-value objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an helper object for the references of the objects and iterate the key/value pairs of the given data.

```js
var data = [{ Country: "US", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2" }, { Country: "US", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2" }, { Country: "CN", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7" }, { Country: "CN", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7" }],
    reference = {},
    result = data.reduce((r, { Country, ...o }) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (!reference[k]) {
                reference[k] = { _: [] };
                r.push({ [k]: reference[k]._ });
            }
            if (!reference[k][Country]) {
                reference[k]._.push(reference[k][Country] = { Country, value: 0 });
            }
            reference[k][Country].value += +v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```js
const extractDates = objArr => Object .entries (objArr .reduce (
  (a, {Country, ...rest}) => Object .entries (rest) .reduce ((a, [date, val]) => ({
    ...a,
    [date]: {...a [date], [Country]: ((a [date] || {}) [Country] || 0) + Number (val)}
  }), a),
  {}
)) .map (([d, o]) => ({[d]: Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => ({Country: k, value: v}))}))

const objArr = [{"Country": "US", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2"}, {"Country": "US", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2"}, {"Country": "CN",  "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"}, {"Country": "CN", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"}]

console .log (extractDates (objArr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This gives the result you asked for in the question, an array of one-key elements.  But note that it's built around this core:

```js
objArr .reduce (
  (a, {Country, ... rest}) => Object .entries (rest) .reduce ((a, [date, val]) => ({
    ...a,
    [date]: {... a [date], [Country]: ((a [date] || {}) [Country] || 0) + Number (val)} 
  }), a),
  {}
)
```

which gives what to me is a much more useful data structure:

```js
{
  "2017-07-12": {CN: 10, US: 3}, 
  "2017-07-13": {CN: 14, US: 4}
}
```

While the final structure  (without the `Object .entries (...) .map (...)` wrapper) could be built in a single pass (see for instance Nina's answer; the one from Nenand Vracar yields a slightly different structure, I find this breakdown cleaner, and think that the intermediate format would in most cases be easier to use.